# how to solve error of aaray to string conversion

Tags: codeigniter-3

I used the following code to insert data.
But it is showing that "Array to string conversion error" for Quantity. The item gets converted to string but the quantity did not convert into a string.
I want to convert quantity into a string.
Please help!

```
  $info['quantity']=array();
  $xyz = count($this->input->post('qty'));
        for ($i=0; $i < $xyz; $i++)  { 
                          //loop
         if ($this->input->post('qty')[$i] != '') {

          
         $info['quantity'][]=json_encode($this->input->post('qty')[$i]);
            
          }
        }
           $info['item']=json_encode($this->input->post('item'));
            
         $this->load->model('view_quotes');
         $res= $this->view_quotes->insert_data('items',$info);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tryed this and solved so I'll just write what I think about that hoping anything will be right lol.

I dont' understand if you want that $info['quantity'] is a String or you want it is an array of Strings.

If you just want 'quantity' to be String don't init it to array before.

> Have you tryed to use
>
> ```
> array_push($info['quantity'], json_encode($this->input->post('qty')[$i]));
> ```
>
> instead of:
>
> ```
> $info['quantity'][]=json_encode($this->input->post('qty')[$i]);
> ```
>
> ?

What "insert_data" do?
If you are just using it to insert data to the db, I don't think you can insert an array in a column.
In this case you should pass an array of 'quantity' and 'items' Strings.